# how to create table grid view fix header with long title name using only CSS?

Tags: css, html, html-table

I am trying to make table grid view using **CSS** only. But when I make long title name design gets distorted.

Here's the **Code**:

```css
.table {
    table-layout:fixed;
    width:500px;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
.header th {
    font-family:Calibri;
    font-size:small;
    font-weight:lighter;
    border-left:1px solid #000;
    background:#d0d0d0;
}
.body_panel {
    display:inline-block;
    width:520px;
    height:300px;
    overflow-y:scroll;
}
.body tr {
    border-bottom:1px solid #d0d0d0;
}
.body td {
    border-left:1px solid #d0d0d0;
    padding-left:3px;
    font-family:Calibri;
    font-size:small;
    overflow:hidden;
    white-space:nowrap;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
}
```

```html
   <table class="table">
<thead class="header">
    <tr>
        <th style="width:20%;">vijay solanki vijayksolanki</th>
        <th style="width:30%;">vijay solanki vijaysolanki</th>
        <th style="width:50%;">vijay solanki vijaysolanki</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
</table>
<div class="body_panel">
<table class="table">
    <tbody class="body">
        <tr>
            <td style="width:20%;">asbkj k kajsb ksb kabkb</td>
            <td style="width:30%;">2</td>
            <td style="width:50%;">3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width:20%;">2</td>
            <td style="width:30%;">2</td>
            <td style="width:50%;">3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width:20%;">2</td>
            <td style="width:30%;">2</td>
            <td style="width:50%;">3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width:20%;">2</td>
            <td style="width:30%;">2</td>
            <td style="width:50%;">3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width:20%;">2</td>
            <td style="width:30%;">2</td>
            <td style="width:50%;">3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width:20%;">2</td>
            <td style="width:30%;">2</td>
            <td style="width:50%;">3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width:20%;">2</td>
            <td style="width:30%;">2</td>
            <td style="width:50%;">3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width:20%;">2</td>
            <td style="width:30%;">2</td>
            <td style="width:50%;">3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width:20%;">2</td>
            <td style="width:30%;">2</td>
            <td style="width:50%;">3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width:20%;">2</td>
            <td style="width:30%;">2</td>
            <td style="width:50%;">3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width:20%;">2</td>
            <td style="width:30%;">2</td>
            <td style="width:50%;">3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width:20%;">2</td>
            <td style="width:30%;">2</td>
            <td style="width:50%;">3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width:20%;">2</td>
            <td style="width:30%;">2</td>
            <td style="width:50%;">3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width:20%;">2</td>
            <td style="width:30%;">2</td>
            <td style="width:50%;">3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width:20%;">2</td>
            <td style="width:30%;">2</td>
            <td style="width:50%;">3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width:20%;">2</td>
            <td style="width:30%;">2</td>
            <td style="width:50%;">3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width:20%;">2</td>
            <td style="width:30%;">2</td>
            <td style="width:50%;">3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width:20%;">2</td>
            <td style="width:30%;">2</td>
            <td style="width:50%;">3</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Please help me into this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Cruise Ships, their Tonnage and Status</title>
<style type="text/css">
  * { padding: 0; margin: 0; }
  table.cruises { 
    font-family: verdana, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    cellspacing: 0; 
    border-collapse: collapse; 
    width: 535px;    
    }
  table.cruises td { 
    border-left: 1px solid #999; 
    border-top: 1px solid #999;  
    padding: 2px 4px;
    }
  table.cruises tr:first-child td {
    border-top: none;
  }
  table.cruises th {
  width:50px!important;   
    border-left: 1px solid #999; 
    padding: 2px 4px;
    background: #6b6164;
    color: white;
    font-variant: small-caps;
    }
  table.cruises td { background: #eee; overflow: hidden; }

  div.scrollableContainer { 
    position: relative; 
    width: 592px; 
    padding-top: 2em; 
    margin: 40px;    
    border: 1px solid #999;
    background: #6b6164;
    }
  div.scrollingArea { 
    height: 240px; 
    overflow: auto; 
    }

  table.scrollable thead tr {
    left: -1px; top: 0;
    position: absolute;
    }

  table.cruises .name     div { width: 108px; }
  table.cruises .operator div { width: 126px; }
  table.cruises .began    div { width: 76px;  text-align:center; }
  table.cruises .tonnage  div { width: 60px;  text-align:center; }
  table.cruises .status   div { width: 160px; }

  table.cruises td.operator { background: #ebcb4d; }
  table.cruises td.tonnage  { background: white; }
  table.cruises td.name     { background: #C7E0C1; }  
  table.cruises td.began    { background: #B7C3E8; }

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="scrollableContainer">
  <div class="scrollingArea">
    <table class="cruises scrollable">
      <thead>
            <tr>
          <th class="name"><div>Name defffdbre fgrgfergfer  fgrgfergfer</div></th>
          <th class="operator"><div>Operator</div></th>
          <th class="began"><div>Name defffdbre fgrgfergfer  fgrgfergfer</div></th>
          <th class="tonnage"><div>Tonnage</div></th>
          <th class="status"><div>Status</div></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
                  <tr>
          <td class="name"><div>Seabourne Sun</div></td>
          <td class="operator"><div>Seabourn Cruise Line</div></td>
          <td class="began"><div>1988</div></td>
          <td class="tonnage"><div></div></td>
          <td class="status"><div >Ended service in 2002, currently operating as Prinsendam</div></td>                        
        </tr>
                  <tr>
          <td class="name"><div>Adventures of the Seas</div></td>
          <td class="operator"><div>Royal Caribbean International</div></td>
          <td class="began"><div>2001</div></td>
          <td class="tonnage"><div>138,000</div></td>
          <td class="status"><div >Operating</div></td>                        
        </tr>
                  <tr>
          <td class="name"><div>Oceanic Independence</div></td>
          <td class="operator"><div>American Hawaiian Cruises / American Global Line</div></td>
          <td class="began"><div>1974</div></td>
          <td class="tonnage"><div>23,719</div></td>
          <td class="status"><div >Named formerly (1951-1974) and subsequently renamed (1982-2006) the Independence, renamed the Oceanic (2006), sold for scrap in 2008 but remains in mothballs</div></td>                        
        </tr>
                  <tr>
          <td class="name"><div>Cunard Ambassador</div></td>
          <td class="operator"><div>Cunard Line</div></td>
          <td class="began"><div>1972</div></td>
          <td class="tonnage"><div>14,160</div></td>
          <td class="status"><div >Burnt 1974, rebuilt into a livestock carrier, renamed Linda Clausen, later Procyon, Raslan. Scrapped 1984 after a second fire.</div></td>                        
        </tr>
                  <tr>
          <td class="name"><div>Aegean Beauty</div></td>
          <td class="operator"><div>Voyages to Antiquity</div></td>
          <td class="began"><div>1973</div></td>
          <td class="tonnage"><div>11,563</div></td>
          <td class="status"><div >Formerly Aegean Dolphin and Aegean I. Operating</div></td>                        
        </tr>
                  <tr>
          <td class="name"><div>Serenade of the Seas</div></td>
          <td class="operator"><div>Royal Caribbean International</div></td>
          <td class="began"><div>2003</div></td>
          <td class="tonnage"><div>90,090</div></td>
          <td class="status"><div >Operating</div></td>                        
        </tr>
                  <tr>
          <td class="name"><div>Queen Elizabeth 2</div></td>
          <td class="operator"><div>Cunard Line</div></td>
          <td class="began"><div>1969</div></td>
          <td class="tonnage"><div>70,327</div></td>
          <td class="status"><div >Left fleet in November 2008</div></td>                        
        </tr>
                  <tr>
          <td class="name"><div>Queen Elizabeth</div></td>
          <td class="operator"><div>Cunard Line</div></td>
          <td class="began"><div>2010</div></td>
          <td class="tonnage"><div>92,000</div></td>
          <td class="status"><div >Operating</div></td>                        
        </tr>
                  <tr>
          <td class="name"><div>Regent Sea</div></td>
          <td class="operator"><div>Regency Cruises</div></td>
          <td class="began"><div>1957</div></td>
          <td class="tonnage"><div></div></td>
          <td class="status"><div >Began operation in 1957 as the Gripsholm (II) for Swedish America Line. Ended operation when Regency went bankrupt in 1995. Was to be converted to a casino ship, but later marked for scrap. Prior to scrapping, was looted by pirates, then sank in heavy seas in 2001.</div></td>                        
        </tr>
                  <tr>
          <td class="name"><div>Allure of the Seas</div></td>
          <td class="operator"><div>Royal Caribbean International</div></td>
          <td class="began"><div>2010</div></td>
          <td class="tonnage"><div>225,000</div></td>
          <td class="status"><div >Starts service in December 2010</div></td>                        
        </tr>
                  <tr>
          <td class="name"><div>Amadea</div></td>
          <td class="operator"><div>Phoenix Reisen</div></td>
          <td class="began"><div>2006</div></td>
          <td class="tonnage"><div>28,717</div></td>
          <td class="status"><div >Operating. Ex-Asuka</div></td>                        
        </tr>
                  <tr>
          <td class="name"><div>Amant</div></td>
          <td class="operator"><div>PhoenixVoyages (Vietnam)</div></td>
          <td class="began"><div>2010</div></td>
          <td class="tonnage"><div></div></td>
          <td class="status"><div >Built in 2010 by a local Vietnamese shipyard (Vuotsong), L'Amant operates on the Mekong River in Vietnam, and is without any doubt the most well constructed vessel sailing in Vietnam.</div></td>                        
        </tr>
                  <tr>
          <td class="name"><div>Oasis of the Seas</div></td>
          <td class="operator"><div>Royal Caribbean Cruise Line</div></td>
          <td class="began"><div>2009</div></td>
          <td class="tonnage"><div>225,282</div></td>
          <td class="status"><div >Operating</div></td>                        
        </tr>
                  <tr>
          <td class="name"><div>Andes</div></td>
          <td class="operator"><div>Royal Mail Lines</div></td>
          <td class="began"><div>1959</div></td>
          <td class="tonnage"><div>27,000</div></td>
          <td class="status"><div >Was liner, became cruise ship in 1959.</div></td>                        
        </tr>
                  <tr>
          <td class="name"><div>Anna Nery</div></td>
          <td class="operator"><div>Companhia de Navegacao Costeirab</div></td>
          <td class="began"><div>1962</div></td>
          <td class="tonnage"><div></div></td>

          <td class="status"><div >Ended service in 1978. Currently operating as Salamis Glory</div></td>                        
        </tr>
                  <tr>
          <td class="name"><div>National Geographic Endeavour</div></td>
          <td class="operator"><div>Lindblad Expeditions</div></td>
          <td class="began"><div>1996</div></td>
          <td class="tonnage"><div></div></td>
          <td class="status"><div >Operating, also known as Endeavour</div></td>                        
        </tr>
                  <tr>
          <td class="name"><div>Liberty of the Seas</div></td>
          <td class="operator"><div>Royal Caribbean International</div></td>
          <td class="began"><div>2007</div></td>
          <td class="tonnage"><div>154,407</div></td>
          <td class="status"><div >Operating</div></td>                        
        </tr>
                  <tr>
          <td class="name"><div>Norwegian Epic</div></td>
          <td class="operator"><div>Norwegian Cruise Line</div></td>
          <td class="began"><div>2010</div></td>
          <td class="tonnage"><div>153,000</div></td>
          <td class="status"><div >Operating</div></td>                        
        </tr>
                  <tr>
          <td class="name"><div>Independence of the Seas</div></td>
          <td class="operator"><div>Royal Caribbean International</div></td>
          <td class="began"><div>2008</div></td>
          <td class="tonnage"><div>154,407</div></td>
          <td class="status"><div >Operating</div></td>                        
        </tr>
                  <tr>
          <td class="name"><div>Navigator of the Seas</div></td>
          <td class="operator"><div>Royal Caribbean International</div></td>
          <td class="began"><div>2002</div></td>
          <td class="tonnage"><div>  138,000</div></td>
          <td class="status"><div >Operating</div></td>                        
        </tr>
                  <tr>
          <td class="name"><div>Caribbean Princess</div></td>
          <td class="operator"><div>Princess Cruises</div></td>
          <td class="began"><div>2004</div></td>
          <td class="tonnage"><div>112,894</div></td>
          <td class="status"><div >Operating</div></td>                        
        </tr>
            </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```